# Automatically switch keyboard layout when any text input field is focused

Tags: windows-10, automation, keyboard-layout

### Problem

So far, I have not been able to find a way to type with one keyboard layout and press hotkeys with another (using the same old Qwerty muscle memory). I have been learning an alternate keyboard layout, which I am mostly happy with, but whenever I need to use software that utilizes more than just copy/paste/undo/redo shortcuts, I frequently press the wrong key since I am used to the Qwerty layout. I could create a new hotkey mapping for the alternate layout within some software, but this solution would be both time-consuming and incomplete.

### Optimal Behavior

I would like to somehow have my keyboard layout switch to the alternate layout whenever the following conditions are all met:

- Any text input field is focused
- Neither Windows nor Control nor Alt keys are currently pressed

### Bottom Line

Does Windows 10 know when a text input field is selected, and can this be used to automatically switch the keyboard layout?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure who flagged this as unclear, but I thought I described my question quite thoroughly. Any specific advice on how to improve it would be nice :)